# При подписании android приложений лучше создавать отдельный ключ или можно подписывать их общим ключом?

Tags: java, android, key

При подписании android приложений лучше для каждого приложения создавать отдельный ключ или можно подписывать их одним своим ключом? Есть ли принципиальная разница?

Answer (score 1):

Технически разницы никакой нет.

Подписывать одним ключом удобно, т.к. не надо хранить множество ключей.

С другой стороны, если ключи будут разные - не так страшно будет один из них потерять.

К тому же стоит учитывать вероятность того, что Google отслеживает какими ключами подписано приложение и, когда вас в GooglePlay забанят (а это неизбежно, т.к. у гугла модерация ботами вечно сбоит) и вы создадите новый аккаунт, то гугл свяжет ваш новый аккаунт со старым по ключам подписи приложений и забанит и новый аккаунт. Вывод - разные ключи лучше.